# Calculate results and then count them based on a criteria in one formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
             A                    B        C          D          E   
1  Sales                         500      200        400        300  
2  Difference (Helper Row)                -60%       100%       -25%
3
4  Criteria:                    -20%
5  Result:                        2
```

Formulas:

```
C2 = C1/B1-1
D2 = D1/C1-1
E2 = E1/D1-1

B5 = COUNTIF(B2:E2,"<"&-0.2)
```

In **Row 1** you can see the sales over the last 4 periods. In **Row 2** the difference between the sales is calculated using the simple formulas described above.

In **Cell B5** I want to show the number of differences (**Row 2**) which are below the criteria in **Cell B4**. 
 *In this case the result is 2 because -60% and -25% are below the criteria of -20%.*

All this works perfectly so far. However, I would prefer to have this system **without** the **Helper Row 2** that I currently use to calculate the differences between the sales in Row 1.

Do you know a formula that gives me the exact same result but calculates the differences automatically and then counts them if they meet a certain criteria?

Comment: Try the edited formula in the question. I changed the -0,2 to -0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:E1/B1:D1-1 <B4))
```

If dealing with potential 0s in Sales

```
 ={SUM(--(IFERROR(C1:E1/B1:D1-1,0)<B4)*--(C1:E1>0))}
```

Comment: Works nice. Do you also have an idea how I could elimnate a #DIV/0! with your formula in case there is cell that has 0 sales?

Comment: O.k. but I meant that it should still keep counting the result and just ignore the #DIV/0 in the count. I might post another question for this issue. Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: Cool. The only thing is that right now 0sale would be considered as -100% and therefore taken into account within the COUNTIF cause they are <-20%. That might be solution in certain cases. However, what if I want that the formula ignores the 0sales completely and just counts the one that are <-20% & <>+/-100%? Thanks a lot for all you effort and the different solutions for the different situations. I will give you an upvote on the answer :-)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.